# Vue3 Element Plus not rendaring the props inside the imported element when testing with the vitest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest, element-plus

I have a very basic component called

`ConfirmModal.vue`

```html
<template>
  <el-dialog v-model="dialogVisible" :title="title" width="30%">
    <span>{{ content }}</span>
    <template #footer>
      <span class="dialog-footer">
        <el-button @click="dialogVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="emit('onConfirm')">
          Confirm
        </el-button>
      </span>
    </template>
  </el-dialog>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { ElButton, ElDialog } from "element-plus";

const props = defineProps({
  show: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: "Are you sure?",
  },
});

const dialogVisible = computed({
  get: () => props.show,
  set: (v: boolean) => emit("update:show", v),
});

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (emitName: "onConfirm"): void;
  (emitName: "update:show", v: boolean): void;
}>();
</script>
```

and a test called

`ConfirmModal.spec.ts`

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { describe, expect, it } from "vitest";
import ConfirmModal from "../ConfirmModal.vue";

describe("ConfirmModal.vue", () => {
  it("render the modal", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(ConfirmModal, {
      props: {
        show: true,
        content: "something",
      },
    });

    expect(wrapper.find("span").text()).toContain("something");
  });
});
```

The test is failing like this

```
 FAIL  components/__tests__/ConfirmModal.spec.ts > ConfirmModal.vue > render the modal
Error: Cannot call text on an empty DOMWrapper.
 ❯ Object.get ../node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.esm-bundler.mjs:1513:27
 ❯ components/__tests__/ConfirmModal.spec.ts:14:31
     12|     });
     13| 
     14|     expect(wrapper.find("span").text()).toContain("something");
       |                               ^
     15|   });
     16| });
```

I'm not sure what is missing here.